# Cache config table and access it globally Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, caching, configuration

I've a `Configuration` model with its table in database named `configurations`.

It has 3 columns:
id, key, and value

I'd like to cache all the key/value pairs from this table for better performance and less database transactions.

**What I've done so far:**
I've created a `Provider` named `ConfigurationsServiceProvider` and following is the code for `register()` method:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('configurations', function ($app) {
        return $app['cache']->remember('configurations', 60, function () {
            return Configuration::pluck('key', 'value')->toArray();
        });
    });
}
```

I've registered the provider in `config/app.php` as well.

**Now I want to achieve the following:**

- Access these configuration key/value pairs globally by calling a method 
  for example `configurations('key')`
- Configurations data should be cached forever, for all users. It should only be re-cached when user inserts/updates any key/value record in database table
- Not important but it would be really great if I could somehow merge and access the `configurations` data with Laravel framework's global `config` method.

Also, kindly suggest if there's any better way, other than `.env`, to store dynamic config data for application from user interface.

Comment: you definitely can, you could adapt this to your needs https://github.com/lagbox/settings    similar idea, cache and pulls from laravel config

Comment: These are 3 questions not one

Comment: @Saly3301 all questions are related to the main question, so instead of creating multiple threads it's better to ask related questions in one post

Comment: your down vote is not very helpful

Comment: That would be the case if Stack Overflow was a help center or a forum, it's not, questions should be very specific to one single problem so future visitors can find the solutions easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case is a helper function loaded via composer

Let's say `app/Helpers.php`

```php
<?php

function configurations($key)
{
    return \Cache::rememberForever("config-$key", function () use ($key) {
        return Configuration::where('key', $key)->first()->value;
    });
}
```

And autoload it in `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

But you would still have to manually purge the cache when value of key changes

Hope this helps

Comment: so you are saying whenever there's any insert/update db transaction made, data against that key should be re-cached manually?

Comment: and using a provider is not really needed

Comment: You can also make a `\DB::listen` call but I wouldn't recommend that for performance issues